# On my minecraft SMP i need to port forward for someone outside my network to connect. What does this mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My friend cant connect to my Minecraft server from their house](https://superuser.com/questions/280660/allowing-a-friend-to-connect-over-the-internet-to-a-minecraft-server-ive-hosted)

My friend and I want a multiplayer server to play on so i'm making one.

Comment: Just use hamachi. Works for me. Simplest multiplayer setup ever. It's free and you don't even need to forward a port at all.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into a deeply technical explanation of how the internet works and whatnot; computers in Casa Smith cannot "see" computers in Casa Lee.

If you are hosting a server on a local machine at home, you need to configure your router to, when asked for a specific port number, forward that request to a specific machine on the appropriate port.

For the details on this process, a better bet is probably [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

**Edit:** On a tangentially related note; server software for Minecraft isn't exactly lightweight, so you need to make sure that you internet connection is beefy enough to support the protocol, as well as that the machine running the server is powerful enough to deal.

Additionally, you probably don't want to run the server and your own client on the same box unless you run a real powerhouse of a machine.

Comment: Wow. That makes me feel really good about the computer I run a client and server on. :) then again, I only ever have 3 people on my server.